# Why my PassBook isn't valid or outdate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passbook

I generate one passbook using [this gem](https://github.com/frozon/passbook) in rails and it seen that works but when I open the passbook .pkpass file I see this message:

[image: Invalid Passbook]

It's in spanish but basically it says that this card isn't valid anymore.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "formatVersion" : 1,
  "passTypeIdentifier" : "{MY PASS ID HERE}",
  "serialNumber" : "E5982H-I2",
  "teamIdentifier" : "{MY TEAM ID HERE}",
  "webServiceURL" : "https://example.com/passes/",
  "authenticationToken" : "vxwxd7J8AlNNFPS8k0a0FfUFtq0ewzFdc",
  "barcode" : {
    "message" : "123456789",
    "format" : "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
    "messageEncoding" : "iso-8859-1"
  },
  "locations" : [
    {
      "longitude" : -122.3748889,
      "latitude" : 37.6189722
    },
    {
      "longitude" : -122.03118,
      "latitude" : 37.33182
    }
  ],
  "organizationName" : "CROCANTICKETS SL",
  "description" : "Paw Planet Coupon",
  "logoText" : "Paw Planet",
  "foregroundColor" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
  "backgroundColor" : "#FF4B33",
  "coupon" : {
    "primaryFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "offer",
        "label" : "Any premium dog food",
        "value" : "20% off"
      }
    ],
    "auxiliaryFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "expires",
        "label" : "EXPIRES",
        "value" : "2016-04-24T10:00-05:00",
        "isRelative" : true,
        "dateStyle" : "PKDateStyleShort"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Expiration Keys in the [Passbook Package Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW1) check the `expirationDate` and `voided` keys. Since you do not have those in your JSON, it might be added by the gem you are using.